# move python module from exising environment to anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to use 'openface' module on python 3, anaconda.
so I referred to here.

https://github.com/samotiian/Installing_openface_with_anaconda

I don't know why, but it seems that the modules were installed on my existing python,not anaconda environment.

when I import these modules from python(not anaconda environment), it works well.

```
unknownpgr@unknownpgr:~$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>> import openface
>>>
```

But It gives such errors when imported from anaconda environment.

```
(opencv) unknownpgr@unknownpgr:~$ python
Python 3.6.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov  4 2017, 10:10:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openface
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openface'
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
>>>
```

So my question is : 
I how can I move these modules from existing environment to anaconda?

(I'm sorry that I'm not good at English. But maybe you can understand what I want to say.)

---

After some reinstall, I found that the problem was working directory.
I was working on /home/openface, so I moved 'openface' to ~/anaconda3/envs/myenvironmet/
and It worked well.

(I'm new to linux and python programming, so I don't know why. Please let me know if you know why python module importing is directory depended to directory.)

Comment: You can set PYTHONPATH variable with 2 paths. One will be pointing towards you default python distribution path and another anaconda one. That way if you start anaconda Python and import some librabry which is not there then it'll look into default python distribution path next.

Comment: Don't move anything. Just reinstall properly in the correct location.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you explain it in more detail?
do you means that I should run setup.py after activate anaconda environment?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what you should do

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks very much. it's solved, very simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess while installing you did not activate your anaconda environment. Repeat the steps after activating your anaconda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the package folder from the

```
PYTHONHOME/lib/site-packages
```

to

```
ANACONDAHOME/lib/site-packages
```

Should work. Worked for me.